# gitlab-runner passes wrong arguments to custom image

Tags: java, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have written a small CLI using Java, [Argparse4j](https://argparse4j.github.io/usage.html), and packaged it in docker using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:18

ENV JAR_NAME "my-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

ENV PROJECT_HOME /opt/app
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_HOME

WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME
COPY run.sh $PROJECT_HOME/run.sh
RUN chmod +x $PROJECT_HOME/run.sh

COPY target/$JAR_NAME $PROJECT_HOME/cli.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
```

The last line of the Dockerfile then invokes a simple bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar ./cli.jar "$@"
```

The CLI I wrote has three main actions: upload, download and apply. Therefore argparse4j **expects** one of these actions to be passed as the first parameter, i.e.

```bash
java -jar cli.jar download #... whatever other argument
```

This works just fine when running the docker image locally, but completely fails when running in the CI pipeline:

```yaml
download:
  stage: download
  image: <url>/my-image:<tag>
  variables:
    URL: <URL>
    API_KEY: <API_KEY>
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  script:
    - download -f zip -u true test-download.zip
```

This is the error that is returned:

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:01
Using docker image sha256:<sha> for <url>/my-image:<tag> with digest <url>/my-image:<tag>@sha256:<sha> ...
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
usage: tool [-h] ACTION ...
tool: error:  invalid  choice:  'sh'  (choose  from  'upload',  'download',
'apply')
```

I have tried following the suggestion in [gitlab-runner doesn't run ENTRYPOINT scripts in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401876/gitlab-runner-doesnt-run-entrypoint-scripts-in-dockerfile) but I can't seem to get the CI part to work correctly.

I would like to avoid using the `entrypoint` directive as it needs to be used on multiple files, so I rather fix the issue at the root.

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a bit of research, I have been able to find a solution that works for me.

From my research (and as Pierre B. pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75108233/2287089)), Gitlab essentially tries to inject a shell script that performs a check for which shell is available.

Now, my solution is in no way elegant, but does achieve what I wanted. I modified the Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM openjdk:18-bullseye

ENV JAR_NAME "my-jar.jar"

ENV PROJECT_HOME /opt/app
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_HOME

WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME
COPY run.sh $PROJECT_HOME/run.sh
RUN chmod +x $PROJECT_HOME/run.sh

COPY target/$JAR_NAME $PROJECT_HOME/cli.jar

RUN  echo '#!/bin/bash \njava $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar $PROJECT_HOME/cli.jar "$@"' > /usr/bin/i18n &&  \
     chmod +x /usr/bin/i18n

ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
```

And also modified the `run.sh` script this way:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -n "$CI" ]]; then
    echo "this block will only execute in a CI environment"
    exec /bin/bash
else
    echo "Not in CI. Running the image normally"
    java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar ./cli.jar "$@"
fi
```

This works because Gitlab, in its list of [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), provides a `CI` env var that is set when the script is running on the CI. By doing so, I skip the java invocation but leave it in the case I need to use it when not on a CI.

Now when I need to use my image, all I need to specify in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is this:

```yaml
download:
  stage: download
  image: <url>/my-image:<tag>
  variables:
    URL: <URL>
    API_KEY: <API_KEY>
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  script:
    - i18n download -f zip -u true test-download.zip # This calls the script that was injected in the Dockerfile
```

This way I essentially mimic an actual CLI, and can use it in all my projects that require this tool.

I am not sure though why I need to "echo" the script for the CLI, and I can't simply copy it. For some reason the env variables are not passed down and I couldn't spend any more time debugging it. So for now, it will stay like this.

If you have any recommendations on how to clean this up, please leave some comments and I will edit my answer!

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to avoid using the entrypoint directive as it needs to be used on multiple files, so I rather fix the issue at the root.

You can change your Dockerfile instead to keep default `ENTRYPOINT` (as `openjdk:18` doesn't define any entrypoint, it will be empty):

```
FROM openjdk:18

# ...

# ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"] # remove this

# Add run.sh to path to be able to use `run.sh` from any directory
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/opt/app"
```

And update your `run.sh` to specify full path to `jar`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar $PROJECT_HOME/cli.jar "$@"
```

Now your container will start in Gitlab without having to specify `entrypoint` keyword for job. You can then setup something like this:

```yaml
download:
  stage: download
  image: <url>/my-image:<tag>
  variables:
    URL: <URL>
    API_KEY: <API_KEY>
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  script:
  # Specify command using run.sh
  # This command is run from within your container
  # Note that script is not an argument passed on your image startup
  # But independent commands run within your container using shell
  - run.sh download -f zip -u true test-download.zip
```

Notes:

- Gitlab won't run your script in Dockerfile's `WORKDIR` but [in a dedicated directory where your project will be cloned.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#custom-build-directories). Using `./` will look for script and jar in current directory at the moment your command is run, but they wouldn't be found if not run from `/opt/app`. Specyfing full path to jar and adding your `run.sh` script to `PATH` make sure they'll be found wherever your `run.sh` from. Alternatively you could run `cd /opt/app` in your job's script but it may cause unwanted side effects.
- Without `ENTRYPOINT` you won't be able to run Docker commands like this

  ```
  docker run " <url>/my-image:<tag>" download ...
  ```

  You'll need to specify either `COMMAND` or `--entrypoint` such as

  ```
  docker run "<url>/my-image:<tag>" run.sh download ...
  docker run --entrypoint run.sh "<url>/my-image:<tag>" download ...
  ```
- You specified not wanting to do this, but [overriding image `entrypoint` on your job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#override-the-entrypoint-of-an-image) seems a much simpler and straightforward solution. Using multiple files you may leverage Gitlab's [`extends`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) and [`include`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include).

---

And now for the fun part

> what is happening

When Gitlab run your container for a job it will use the `entrypoint` defined in your Dockerfile by default. [From doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#override-the-entrypoint-of-an-image):

> 1. The runner starts a Docker container **using the defined entrypoint**. The default from Dockerfile that may be overridden in the
>    .gitlab-ci.yml file.
> 2. The runner attaches itself to a running container.
> 3. The runner prepares a script (the combination of before_script, script, and after_script).
> 4. The runner sends the script to the container’s shell stdin and receives the output.

And what the doc doesn't say is that [Gitlab will try to use various form of `sh` as Docker *command*](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-runner/blob/39ebe9ab9f0f9c14e9745d1a59a15018880c6962/shells/bash.go#L16). In short for step 1. it's like running this Docker command:

```bash
# Gitlab tries to run container for your job
docker run -it "<url>/my-image:<tag>" sh
```

It doesn't work as Gitlab will use default entrypoint and the final command run in Docker is:

```bash
./run.sh sh
```

Where `./run.sh` is the `entrypoint` from Dockerfile and `sh` is the `command` provided by Gitlab. It causes the error you see:

> `tool: error:  invalid  choice:  'sh'  (choose  from  'upload',  'download', 'apply')`

You never reach your job's script (step 4). See [ENTRYPOINT vs. CMD for details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).

Furthermore, the script you define is a command itself. Even if your container started, it wouldn't work as the following command would be run inside your container:

```bash
download -f zip -u true test-download.zip

# 'download' command doesn't exists
# You probably want to run instead something like:

/opt/app/run.sh download -f zip -u true test-download.zip
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! In the end I went for another approach (check my answer), but since you spent the time explaining all of this, the bounty is yours

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your script in single quotes:

```
script:
    - 'download -f zip -u true test-download.zip'
```

EDIT:

Oh, this [open bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27706) in gitlab could be relevant to you

Comment: This is not a bug, but a misusage of Gitlab. Job's `script` is not passed as argument to container entrypoint (_command_ in Docker terminology) but rather run within container after it's started.